# numOfColors recursive function JAVA

Tags: java, recursion

I trying to write recursive function in Java.

The function needs to count for me all the diffrents values in array.

i.e

```
{{1,1,1,1},{4,4,4,4},{3,3,1,1}}
```

The recursive function returns 3 (1,4,3)

This is the function that i need to write:

```
int numOfColors(int[][] map)
```

What I have been tried:

```
public static int numOfColors(int[][] arr) {

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int colors=0;
    int contains = arr[i][j];
    if (arr== null) { 
        return 0;
    } else if (arr[i][j] != 0&& arr[i][j]!=contains) { 
        colors ++;
    }
    return numOfColors(arr) + 1;
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

How can i fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: recursion need base case, the case when method should stop calling itself again and return. There is no basecase in this code.

Comment: The way this is written you are just evaluating that `arr[0][0] != arr[0][0]` over and over again (recursively). There is no change at all when you recurse and you have no real base case to stop you (`arr` won't be null except possibly on the first invocation).

Comment: Your recursive function "won't finish" if your array is != null, that's why you have this kind of exception.

Comment: Also, this doesn't strike me as a problem that requires a recursive solution. Iterating over the two arrays and putting everything you find in a `Set` seems to be the most straight forward way to solve this.

Comment: Yeah,  im unddrstood my mistakes but dont know to fix them

Answer (score 2):

Below is one way of finding count of unique values using recursion and without using any `Set` or `List` -

```
package test;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr = { { 4, 2, 2, 1, 4 }, { 4, 4, 3, 1, 4 }, { 1, 1, 4, 2, 1 }, { 1, 4, 0, 2, 2 }, { 4, 1, 4, 1, 1 } };
        System.out.println(numOfColors(arr));

    }

    public static int numOfColors(int[][] arr) {
        int unique = 0;
        if (arr.length == 0) {
            return unique;
        } else {
            int[] subArr = arr[arr.length - 1];

            outerLoop: for (int i = 0; i < subArr.length; i++) {
                int j = i + 1;
                for (; j < subArr.length; j++) {
                    if (subArr[i] == subArr[j]) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (j == subArr.length) {
                    int k = 0;
                    for (; k < arr.length - 1; k++) {
                        for (int l = 0; l < arr[k].length; l++) {
                            if (subArr[i] == arr[k][l]) {
                                continue outerLoop;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (k == arr.length - 1) {
                        unique++;
                    }
                }
            }
            int[][] dest = new int[arr.length - 1][];
            System.arraycopy(arr, 0, dest, 0, arr.length - 1);
            unique += numOfColors(dest);
            return unique;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**
5

Note that this problem can be solved without recursion easily. Also, above code can be make easy using `Set`

Comment: I have been tried to run it but it isnt return the current answer

Comment: I'm trying to run your solution with {{4,2,2,1,4},{4,4,3,1,4},{1,1,4,2,1},{1,4,0,2,2},{4,1,4,1,1}}, the excepted value is 5 and i got NullOfPointerExeption, I'm trying to change the first "If" to if (map == null || map.length == 0) but it still not return 5

Comment: btw, the array alaways will be NxN

Comment: @CSharpBeginner I have executed this program with your given input, and it is returning 5. I hope you have copied it correctly. And I do not have any "map" variable so what are trying to change

Comment: @CSharpBeginner  I have updated complete code including main method and your given input, it is giving excepted result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should store unique values in `Set` and build final result base on it size. Here is one from many solutions:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] map = new int[][] {{1,1,1,1},{4,4,4,4},{3,3,1,1}};

        System.out.println(numOfColors(map));
    }

    public static int numOfColors(int[][] map) {
        HashSet<Integer> result = new HashSet<Integer>();

        numOfColorsImpl(map, 0, result);

        return result.size();
    }

    private static void numOfColorsImpl(int[][] map, int rowIndex, Set<Integer> result) {
        if (rowIndex == map.length)
            return;

        for (int value : map[rowIndex]) {
            result.add(value);
        }

        numOfColorsImpl(map, rowIndex + 1, result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive helper function that removes duplicates.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] strg) {
        int[][] arr = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 1, 1}};
        numOfColors(arr);
    }
    static int numOfColors(int[][] map) {
        ArrayList<Integer> intlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int o = 0; o < map.length; o++) {
            for (int n = 0; n < map[o].length; n++) {
                intlist.add(map[o][n]);
            }
        }
        intlist = removeDuplicates(intlist, 0);
        System.out.println(intlist.size()+" " +intlist);
        return intlist.size();
    }
    static ArrayList<Integer> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<Integer> list, int counter) {
        if (list == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        if (counter < list.size()) {
            if (list.contains(list.get(counter))) {
                if (list.lastIndexOf(list.get(counter)) != counter) {
                    list.remove(list.lastIndexOf(list.get(counter)));
                    counter--;
                }
            }
            removeDuplicates(list, ++counter);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Output

```
3 [1, 4, 3]
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/eUZDV0)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think recursion is necessary in this case, so I will explain the way I would go about it. I will refer to arr as array A.  First, you create a hash set of numbers that you have seen already, which we will call hash set B.  Then, you can loop through array A, processing each element.  Check if hash set B contains that element.  If it does, continue, if not, add that value to hash set B.  After the loop, return the length of hash set B, or the entire set if you want to see what the unique values are.

For example:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Class {
        public static void main(String[] args){
                int[][] A = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 1, 1}};
                System.out.println("Number of different values: " + countUniqueVals(A));
        }

        public static int countUniqueVals(int[][] A){
                HashSet<Integer> B = new HashSet<Integer>();
                for (int row = 0; row < A.length; row++)
                        for (int col = 0; col < A[row].length; col++)
                                B.add(A[row][col]);
                return B.size();
        }
}
```

Comment: First, this isn't recursive. Second, why the heck are you using a `Vector` here? It's a completely inappropriate data structure because a) it's synchronized and there is absolutely no need for that and b) it's a List-like structure. A `Set` like `HashSet` is far more appropriate.

Comment: @JornVernee I don't think recursion is necessary in this case.

Comment: @Todd You are right, a set would be better for this.  I'll fix it, but I think that vectors are easier for someone who is new to coding.

Comment: Thanks, but it isnt recursive

Comment: @CSharpBeginner Is there a reason that you want it to be recursive?  This doesn't seem like a case where recursion would be useful.  Processing each element of the array seems like a more simple solution.